# Prevent printing of elements in HTML

Tags: html, pdf

My website has a menu for simplicity contained within ID:

```
<div id="menu">

..code.. 

</div>
```

When users print in PDF by going FILE->PRINT for example this appears ugly on the PDF document. Is there any way to exclude the `div id="menu"` from being printed?

Comment: have you not heard of `@media print` stylesheets?

Comment: nop... will have a look if it helps :)

Comment: so i can use @media print and set this to "display:none" correct ?

Comment: added an answer with an example of how to implement it, as well as a link to the MDN documentation for it.

Comment: thanks - btw i think i just found out that if I put the css code in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />` it won't work? I will just put the code inline on my header.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example of a print stylesheet to do what you want:

```
@media print {
    #menu {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Within that parent bracket you can do whatever you want from a CSS perspective, but this will hide the `div` you want to hide.

[Here is the MDN documentation on @media, which includes print.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

Answer (score 1):

If you add the following to your css it won't print the menu anymore

```
<style>
    @media print {
        #menu {
        display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
```